# How to use the keyfile settings backend from PyGObject?

Tags: python, introspection, glib, pygobject, gio

GIO (GLib's I/O library) has a backend for GSettings that uses a keyfile. From C, you can create an instance of this backend in order to force use of a keyfile instead of the system registry, using `g_keyfile_settings_backend_new()` and then `g_settings_new_with_backend()`. However, to do this, you must `#define G_SETTINGS_ENABLE_BACKEND` in your code, since the backend public API is unstable.

I would like to do this from Python, using PyGObject (just to be clear, since this term is confusing - this is the GObject introspection library that goes with GTK 3, not the PyGObject that goes with PyGTK and GTK 2.) I can do

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gio
>>> 'SettingsBackend' in dir(Gio)
True
```

However, there's no function corresponding to `g_keyfile_settings_backend_new()` in `dir(Gio)`. If I try instantiating a backend,

```
>>> Gio.SettingsBackend()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

So, does anybody have any pointers? Or maybe the Python module wasn't compiled with `G_SETTINGS_ENABLE_BACKEND` and I'm out of luck?

Comment: I have no idea if this is related, but I had a similar issue when trying to use GLib.KeyFile and it turned out to be a bug that someone fixed in the version Ubuntu 12.04 uses.  I have yet to track down the place where the fix was made.  You may want to try a VM with a newer copy of the OS, if possible, or check gnome's bug tracker.

Comment: I can confirm that this problem isn't fixed in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I can get it to work by recompiling gobject-introspection. I submitted a bug on bugzilla.gnome.org: [link](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682702)